# Exclude url from filter-mapping in web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I am using spring mvc and I need to exclude urls from filter-mapping. It means, I have static content like pictures and css and js ... and I need to not process these request, for example from security filter. I tried urlrewrite, but I was not able to redirect the urls directly to defaultServlet, which is defined in catalina web.xml. I need to jump over filters, because I have a lot of them. Is there a way? Thanks

EDIT - I thought maybe I could create filter which will if decided jump over other filters and execute the servlet at the end. Is it possible to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I used:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>Warn</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

and url rewrite was defined:

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
<rule>
    <from>/static/**</from>
    <to>/static/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some example solution:

http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/09/webxml-problem-and-solution-for-url.html

another one:

http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1024/

and another one:

http://blog.ericdaugherty.com/2010/02/excluding-content-from-url-pattern-in.html

Hope that helps...

Konrad