# How to NOT run servlet filters for specific url-patterns?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I'd like to create a servlet filter that applies to all my URL paths except for a few a specify (or ideally specified by a regex).

Is that possible? Unfortunately I can't change the paths such that all of my other URLs start with something common....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude url from filter-mapping in web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607479/exclude-url-from-filter-mapping-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this via spec-compliant configuration. You do have a couple of options:

1. Re-write your `<filter-mapping>`s so that they are much more specific (e.g. `/foo` becomes `/foo/bar` and `/foo/baz` but not `/foo/foo`).
2. Alter the code in the filter so that it knows about a list of "excludes" URI patterns. You can even use `<init-param>` if you want to configure them in `web.xml`, but you'll have to do the real work yourself.
3. Add a set of `<filter-mapping>`s and `<servlet-mapping>`s that *do* share a common URI prefix and start using *those* (leaving the old mappings in effect).

Comment: Thanks! For now, I'm going with option 2, but may end up refactoring all the paths as in 1.

Comment: Yeah, I think that option #2 is the one that is probably the fastest path from point A to point B.